# SEO Keyword Counter

Tags: javascript

I wrote a simple JavaScript SEO keyword counter. The user enters their SEO keyword in one field then enters their webpage text in a textarea field. It then calculates (in realtime, as the user types) how many times the keyword appears in the web page text. It also calculates the keyword density.

It works but probably is more complicated than it needs to be.

**My code is as follows:**

```js
function myFunction() {
 
 var numberOfTimesKeyword = 0;
 
 // Prep the text ////////////////////////////////////
 // Remove all characters but a-z AND 0-9 AND spaces
 var pageText = textarea.value.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '');
 
 // Remove double spaces
 pageText = pageText.replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ');

 // Trim beginning and ending spaces
 pageText = pageText.trim();
 // End: Prep the text ////////////////////////////////////
 
 // Make textarea values into array
 var pageTextArray = pageText.split(" ");
 
 // Go through array and find out how many times the keyword appears
 for(var i in pageTextArray) {
  
  if (pageTextArray[i] == textfield.value) {
   numberOfTimesKeyword++;
  }
 
 }

 // Find keyword density
 var keywordDensity = (numberOfTimesKeyword / pageTextArray.length) * 100; 
 
  if (numberOfTimesKeyword > 0) { // The keyword appears at least once
   containsText.innerHTML = "The keyword appears <strong>" + numberOfTimesKeyword + "</strong> time(s).";
  } else {
   containsText.innerHTML = "<strong>Does not contain keyword.</strong>";
  }
   
  densityText.innerHTML = "<strong>Keyword Density ((# of times keyword appears / total words) * 100):</strong> " + Math.ceil(keywordDensity) + "%";
  lengthText.innerHTML = "<strong>Array Length:</strong> " + pageTextArray.length;
}
```

```html
<p>
<strong>SEO Keyword:</strong>
<br>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" oninput="myFunction()">
</p>
<p>
<strong>Webpage Text:</strong>
<br>
<textarea name="textarea" cols="20" rows="5" id="textarea" oninput="myFunction()"></textarea>
</p>
<hr>
<p>
<span id="containsText"><strong>Does not contain keyword.</strong></span>
<br>
<span id="densityText"><strong>Keyword Density ((# of times keyword appears / total words) * 100):</strong> ---</span>
<br>
<span id="lengthText"><strong>Array Length:</strong> ---</span>
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Split your function into two parts: one which counts a keyword within a paragraph of text, and one which updates your HTML elements.  These are different concerns.  One is a pure function, and one is concerned with mutating the DOM to present results.
2. Prefer clear code to comments.  Remember that comments are just noise and visual clutter when the code itself is clear (which yours was).  When you do want to add comments for extra clarity, keep them brief.
3. Prefer functional method chaning to temporary variables, when possible.
4. Use clear names rather than implementation details: Word count rather than Array Length.

```js
function keywordStats(text, keyword) {
  
  var words      = text.replace(/[^\w\s]/gi, '') // only words and spaces
                   .replace(/\s\s+/g, ' ')       // remove double spaces
                   .trim()
                   .split(' '),
      wordCnt    = words.length,
      keywordCnt = words.reduce((m,x) => m + (x == keyword) ? 1 : 0, 0),
      density    = (keywordCnt / wordCnt) * 100;
  
  return { wordCnt, keywordCnt, density };
}

function updatePageStats() {
  var stats   = keywordStats(textarea.value, textfield.value),
      setHTML = (id, html) => document.getElementById(id).innerHTML = html;

  setHTML('containsText', 
    stats.keywordCnt
    ? "The keyword appears <strong>" + stats.keywordCnt + "</strong> time(s)."
    : "<strong>Does not contain keyword.</strong>");

  setHTML('densityText', 
    "<strong>Keyword Density ((# of times keyword appears / total words) * 100):</strong> " + Math.ceil(stats.density) + "%");

  setHTML('lengthText', 
    "<strong>Total Word Count:</strong> " + stats.wordCnt);
}
```

```html
<p>
<strong>SEO Keyword:</strong>
<br>
<input type="text" name="textfield" id="textfield" oninput="updatePageStats()">
</p>
<p>
<strong>Webpage Text:</strong>
<br>
<textarea name="textarea" cols="20" rows="5" id="textarea" oninput="updatePageStats()"></textarea>
</p>
<hr>
<p>
<span id="containsText"><strong>Does not contain keyword.</strong></span>
<br>
<span id="densityText"><strong>Keyword Density ((# of times keyword appears / total words) * 100):</strong> ---</span>
<br>
<span id="lengthText"><strong>Word Count:</strong> ---</span>
</p>
```

Comment: +1 Thank you for your feedback and code revisions. I implemented most of your feedback but found that `keywordCnt = words.reduce((m,x) => m + (x == keyword) ? 1 : 0, 0),`caused the code to not work with Safari 9.1.1 (OS X 10.11.5). This also caused the code to not work with the code snippet you provided. It did work fine with Chrome & Firefox. The `setHTML` also caused the code to not work using Safari.

Comment: I believe safaris ES6 support may be lacking